# Is this the correct way to specific "Backup everything except for these few files" in backup rule?

Tags: android

Currently, I have a legacy app which I do not explicitly mentioning any backup rule. So, my observation is that, it just backup everything.

Recently, I still want to backup everything, but want to have an ability to exclude certain files from being backup.

I was wondering, is this the correct way to mention "Backup everything except for these few files" in backup rule?

I had gone through https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup but it isn't super clear.

I was wondering, will the below backup rule correctly serve my purpose (Backup everything except for these few files)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="file" path="."/>
    <include domain="database" path="."/>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
    <include domain="external" path="."/>
    <include domain="root" path="."/>

    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="androidx.work.util.id.xml" />
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="com.google.android.gms.appid.xml" />
</full-backup-content>
```